# TFS plugin can't insert credentials

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I have ubuntu 20.04.

Installed eclipse 4.18.

Installed TFSEclipsePlugin-UpdateSiteArchive-14.135.0.zip from (https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases)

When I try to define the TFS server, I click in "Enter Credentials..." but nothing happens.
[tfs setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr2M0.png)

Also enabled the option to accept untrusted certificates.
[configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6tas.png)

What is missing?

Comment: According to official link of [team-explorer-everywhere](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere#what-is-team-explorer-everywhere), give a try to use Eclipse with version 4.2 to 4.6. `Supported on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. Compatible with IDEs that are based on Eclipse 4.2 to 4.6`

Comment: I tried with eclipse 4.6, but the problem remains.
There's any other way to connect to a TFS server? If I have the latest eclipse version, how can I connect to a TFS server?

Answer (score 0):

With latest [14.137.0](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) you can use it again in Linux with latest eclipse